# Get list of File object of Internal memory

Tags: android

I want to write something like file manager, but don't understand how get begin directory(not SD card), namely all besides sd card. I try like this:

```
File myDir=new File("/");
File myDir=Environment.getDataDirectory();
File myDir=Environment.getRootDirectory();
```

.. I try to use `myDir.getParent()`, I don't know what to do, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line you wrote should work.

I just tried the below code to list all files in root directory.

```
File f = new File("/");
if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
    String[] list = f.list();
    for (String s : list) {
        Log.d(TAG, s);
    }
}
```

It worked.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why it didn't work first time, but you are android wizard=)